# Fundamental theorem of calculus and complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am teaching myself complex integration, and unfortunately my text book has left me confused as to when I can apply  the Fundamental theorem of calculus for complex integration.

Consider the following on the unit circle (centered at $0$ with radius $1$)

$$\oint cosec^{2}\left ( z \right )$$

i believe this integral to be $0$ because the  antederivative is $cot(z)$ and is defined on the unit circle, and $cosec(z)$ is continuous on the unit circle.

The fact that the unit circle contains $0$, on which neither $cosec(z)$ nor $cot(z)$ is defined is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is that the statements above hold true on the path itself.

consider now

$$\oint \frac{1}{z}$$ also on the unit circle

is the sole reason the FTOC fails to apply , that the antiderivative $ln(z)$ is not well defined at $z=1$ , assuming a branch cut $[0,+infinity]$ ?

and therefore if we took the same integral on the unit circle minus ${1}$, would the integral exist and be $= 0$ ?

Thank you

Comment: *"The fact that the unit circle contains 0, on which neither cosec(z) nor cot(z) is defined is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is that the statements above hold true on the path itself."* No, this is **wrong**.

Comment: I still think that your link makes demands 9on the behaviour of the function on and inside the contour rather than merely on the contour itself , which is all the FToC requires. After all, why would the behaviour at 0 matter when computing the integral on the unit circle? I think perhaps the reason is that for cosec^2 the antederivative is well defined on the path, but that of 1/z is not. 0 is a singularity of the antederivatives in both cases, but in the case of 1/z only is 0 also a branch point of the antederivative.  This means that where the branch cut hits the circle there is trouble.

Comment: This would also explain why only the coefficient of 1/z matters in Laurent expansions amongst all the z^n: it is the only one for which the antederivative has a branch point and branch cut.

Comment: The reason it is not zero (I believe), is because the antederivative, ln(z) has a branch cut that runs through the unit circle. In the same vein, the reason that the integral of z^n is zero for n<>-1 is because the antederivative in such cases has no branch cut - merely an (irrelevant) singularity at 0. It is not that 0 is singularity that matters, or even that 0 is a branch point, but the fact that there is a branch cut hitting the contour. do you agree with this or do you think I am on the wrong track?

Comment: Ok, then yes. I was much disturbed by one of your sentence (the one in italic in my first comment). It's not *that* irrelevant to the question. Sorry anyway :o)

Comment: Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the integral of $\csc^2{z}$ does indeed vanish over the unit circle.  The reason is that the behavior of $\csc{z}$ as $z \to 0$ is

$$\csc{z} = \frac1{z} + \frac16 z + O(z^3) $$

Thus,

$$\csc^2{z} = \frac1{z^2} + \frac13 + O(z^2)$$

Because the coefficient of $1/z$ in $\csc^2{z}$ is zero, the integral about the unit circle (or any closed loop about the origin) of $\csc^2{z}$ is zero.

Comment: thank you, however I claim that it may be possible to  get the same result without any calculation: the antederivative of cosec^2 is well defined on the path (eg has no branch cut hitting the circle) therefore the integral is 0. I am not sure if that is true though :(

Comment: @user3203476: You're right.  However, I was trying to alleviate your confusion as to why the integral evaluated directly is zero given that there is a pole at the origin.  I hope that the answer brought some consistency.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If $f,F$ are holomorphic in an open set $U$ and $F'=f$ in $U,$ then $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = 0$ for every closed contour in $U.$ Proof: Because $(F\circ\gamma)' (t) = f(\gamma (t))\gamma '(t),$$$\int_a^b f(\gamma (t))\gamma '(t)\,dt = F(\gamma (b)-F(\gamma (a)) = 0.$$ The OP is certainly right on this. Poles, residues, simple connectedness, Cauchy's Theorem etc. are not a factor here.

Comment: By "here" I mean the case where we have an antiderivative in an open set containing the contour.